# restful send binary data mith post nethod

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, post, binary-data

how i can send binary data with post metht to RESTful api?

i should upload document with restful api.
the Description of the post Functions is.

> The (binary)content of the file should be sent as POST data.

how i can do it?

i try with the code:

```
using RestSharp;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
...
var client = new RestClient("https://myServer.com/rest/");
client.AddHandler("text/html", new RestSharp.Deserializers.JsonDeserializer());      
var contactsRequest = new RestRequest("Documents?f=1&name=file.jpg", Method.POST);
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Penguins.jpg");
contactsRequest.AddBody(bytes);
var contacts = client.Execute(contactsRequest);
```

but it throw Exeption

> The '[' character, hexadecimal value 0x5B, cannot be included in a name.

Comment: the header in the response should say which kind of content is sent in the response's body.

Comment: you can give me example?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know your framework, but this is more or less what you did here: client.AddHandler("text/html", new RestSharp.Deserializers.JsonDeserializer());

Comment: you can put maybe "application/text" or something like that.

Comment: I don't know your classes, but I think you're telling the server that you will send him a "text/html" from a json object, but your're sending a byte array that represent an image...

Comment: It looks like there is a Left Square Bracket somewhere it shouldn't be.